# How to use ffmpeg lt(mod) and gte(mod)

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to mix and swap several second of my video. For example, every 9 second, first 5 second keep original and I want second 8+9 will be 6+7 and vice versa, 6+7 will be 8+9.

I think overlay can work but I still don't know how to work with it.

Comment: No need to delete all of your question to say that the answer works. Better to show that the answer works by [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Basic method is to use select filters to extract frames from segments which are to be shuffled, then adjust those timestamps to set their new position, and then overlay them onto the original video stream.

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf "split=3[base][5to7][7to9];[5to7]select='between(mod(t\,9)\,5\,6.999)',setpts=PTS+2/TB[5to7];[7to9]select='between(mod(t\,9)\,7\,8.999)',setpts=PTS-2/TB[7to9];[base][5to7]overlay=enable='between(mod(t\,9)\,7\,8.999)'[base79];[base79][7to9]overlay=enable='between(mod(t\,9)\,5\,6.999)'" -c:a copy out
```

To do the same for audio, add

`-af "asplit=3[base][5to7][7to9];[base]aselect='not(between(mod(t\,9)\,5\,8.999))',aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[base];[5to7]aselect='between(mod(t\,9)\,5\,6.999)',asetpts=PTS+2/TB,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[5to7];[7to9]aselect='between(mod(t\,9)\,7\,8.999)',asetpts=PTS-2/TB,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[7to9];[base][7to9][5to7]amix=3,volume=3"`

and remove `-c:a copy`.

Comment: thank you so much. I try and it work so sweet. By the way, is there any way I can apply this with audio too? swap both audio and video. I searched but seems that audio can not overlay.